# jQuery Mobile - firing pageshow event only once

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery

I am trying to execute a snippet of JS only once, after the page has completely loaded and JQM has taken care of all the ui modifications (i.e. listviews, buttons, etc.).  I do want it to execute only on that page, and not on subsequent pages.

What I tried first, was pageshow

```
<script>
$('[data-role=page]').live("pageshow", function() {
    alert("Ready!");
}); 
</script>
```

This has the problem that the function is now attached to the page div and gets executed every time any subsequent page gets shown.  However, I only want this to be executed once, and only for the page that contains that JS snippet.

Is there a way to listen to the pageshow event, without actually attaching the function to it.

The only way I was able to do it was by binding and unbinding like this:

```
<script>
$('[data-role=page]').bind("pageshow.test", testfun);

function testfun() {
    alert("Ready!");
    $('[data-role=page]').unbind("pageshow.test", testfun);
}   
</script>
```

But is there a more elegant way to do so?

Comment: To bind to only a single page, use it's ID in the selector rather than `[data-role=page]` which selects all the elements with the `data-role` attribute set to `page`: `$('#my-page').bind('pageinit', ...)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

jQuery has a `one` function to bind an event handler to be executed only once. Check the [reference](http://api.jquery.com/one/).

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of the one function.

Answer (score 4):

The `pageinit` event fires once per page just after the jQuery Mobile framework initializes its widgets; I think it may be what you're looking for.

> **pageinit**
>
> Triggered on the page being initialized, after initialization occurs.
>   We recommend binding to this event instead of DOM ready() because this
>   will work regardless of whether the page is loaded directly or if the
>   content is pulled into another page as part of the Ajax navigation
>   system.

*Source: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0-rc.1/docs/api/events.html*

If you want to bind to a specific page and not the rest, then select only the page you want to alter... Here's an example:

```
<script>
$(document).delegate('#my-page-id', 'pageinit', function() {
    alert("PageInit!");
}); 
</script>
```